# Laravel prepends base url twice

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4, routes

In the project I'm currently building I have a real weird problem that I can't seem to solve.

I am building this project in Laravel 4.1 (I can't use 4.2/5.0/5.1) because of the production servers it has to run on.

Now the problem, my url's that I generate do always get the base url double appended.

So when I do this:

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.ideas.update', $idea->id), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'put'))}}
```

I see this in my source code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://myapp.app:8000/admin/ideas/42" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But when I submit I get: the following in my browser window:

```
http://myapp.app:8000/http://myapp.app:8000/admin/ideas
```

The same issue appears when I do Redirect::route(...) but when I use Redirect::to('url') everything works fine.

Has anyone had this before and knows how I can solve this?

EDIT:

```
Route::get('ideas/{id}/edit', array(
            'as' => 'admin.ideas.edit',
            'uses' => 'IdeasController@edit',
        ));

        Route::put('ideas/{id}', array(
            'as' => 'admin.ideas.update',
            'uses' => 'IdeasController@update',
        ));
```

Comment: Can you add your routes.php file please?

Comment: Edited my original post. But it's not only in this part of my application, It's everywhere over the hole application.

Comment: Browser can do such thing, compare base tag from inspector when it is working correctly and when not and inform us

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can do this:
Try to set the form action this way:

```css
<form  action="{{ url('admin/ideas') . '/' . $idea->id}}" >
```

It should work this way